# Adding onto an input prompt after the user inputs

Tags: python, input, pi

I'm trying to make a "pi-practicing' program in python, and I want the user's input, if correct, to be placed next to the "3.".

I have:

```
numbers = [1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5]

def sequence():
    i = input("3.") 
    y = int(i)
    if y == numbers[0]:
        print ("Good job!")
        #??????
        numbers.pop(0)
        sequence()
    else:
        print("nope")
        sequence()
sequence()
```

So when prompted, if the user enters 1 as the first number, I want the next input prompt to be 3.1, so the user has to enter 4, and so on.

Thank you in advance!
-rt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion a simple while loop would do. It's generally not good practice to leverage global variables:

```
def sequence():
    numbers = [1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5]
    prompt = '3.'
    while numbers:
        i = input(prompt)
        y = int(i)
        if y == numbers[0]:
            print ("Good job!")
            prompt += i
            numbers.pop(0)
        else:
            print("nope")
sequence()
```